# I am trying to convert a int into a char and output the ascii value?

Tags: c++

Before this part of code i have if else if statement to give the int value
It is also randomized, but the only problem is with this part trying to make the outputint variable to become a character ascii value which output is declared as char
right now my array shows the integer variables and not the respective ascii variables

```
output = static_cast<char> (outputint);
array[i][j] = output;
cout << array[i][j] << " ";
```

Comment: `cout << (char)array[i][j] << " ";` may be?

Answer (score 1):

you just have to tell the compiler to print a char, like this:

`cout << (char)array[i][j];`

Or if you want to use C++ style casting:

`cout << static_cast<char>(array[i][j]);`